# does intellij support variables in launch configurations?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, intellij-idea, environment-variables

In eclipse I can include things like the following in the vm args or program args in a launch configuration:

```
-Dsome.system.property=${string.prompt:explanation:default}
```

When you run this, you get a string prompt in a little pop up showing the explanation text and ready with the default, and it allows you to inject properties easily and per run of the application.

I use it a lot for things like specifying whether I want a dev or test instance of the application. You can also do `${env_var:ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME}` to pick up machine specific config, useful for sharing these launch configs between developers.

Is this, or anything similar, supported in IntelliJ Idea? Are there plugins that provide this functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in IntelliJ. To make it easier to share configurations or other project settings between multiple developers, you can use path variables (Settings | Path Variables, see the Help for more information). To customize the options before launching the run configuration, enable the "Before launch | Show Settings" option in the run configuration settings.

Comment: That does look reasonably close. Syntax `$path-variable-name$` picks up the variable, and you can change their values in settings. You can't change their values in the Show Settings dialog before launch though.

Comment: It seems that it's coming soon... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74031

Answer (score 10):

In the 2016 version of IntelliJ at least, you can access environment variables using the brace-enclosed environment variable syntax:

```
${HOME}/path/to/file
```

is expanded properly, but the alternative syntax

```
$HOME/path/to/file
```

does *not* work.

Version Info:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2
Build #IC-162.1628.40, built on August 16, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 5):

Just did this for a machine specific variable in IntelliJ 11.0.2.
Set up a path variable i.e. MY_VARIABLE.
Use in your run config as you would in eclipse : ${MY_VARIABLE}

Comment: should variables like `${TIME}` work?  I tried adding `${TIME}` to the VM options to no avail.

Comment: The syntax is $VARIABLE$, as described here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/path-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anything like that in all my years using IntelliJ IDEA.

You can open a feature request in their [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA), and maybe they'll implement it in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/05/09/setting-global-variables-intellij/) is what you want. it's work on mine project.

e.g.

```
launchctl setenv ANDROID_HOME= /usr/myuser/android_sdk/
and restart intellij
```