# IntelliJ substitution variables/global scope

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, settings

In Eclipse I can set **global variables** which are in scope for `JUnit` tests, main class runners and `maven` builds. In IntelliJ I am setting them up on every run setting for the 3 mentioned. I did define `defaults` in the **run configuration settings** but I wondered, is there not a global definition that can be shared and used by all runners automatically?

Have amended the header according to a valid precision given below. In essence instead of defining a PATH variable or a simple variable in all run settings I'd like to know if I can define them in one central location which is automatically shared by all run configurations.

Comment: Java doesn't have "global variables".

Comment: Java has, public statics are global variables but I was not asking a Java question here, Eclipse has a variable substitution setting, which is global, I was looking for the same for IntelliJ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675705/does-intellij-support-variables-in-launch-configurations

Comment: @1174 : the concept of global variables doesn't exist in Java. What you are referring to are class variables. Can't say I've used IntelliJ all that much. If the link Boris pasted doesn't help, maybe go through IntelliJ's documentation?

Comment: I might have not explained it properly, it is not a duplicate to the mentioned. Suppose I have a variable PATH or java.libary.x, is there a way to define these in one setting instead of in the maven runner, junit default and application runner default?

Comment: I went through the documentation, I could not find it, might be my mistake that I did not find an answer but I really tried.

Comment: @Stultuske global variables, yes, your definition is valid, just different by namespace reference compared to C++ I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so previous answer didnt work but I think this is what you want:
Edit the default setting for the default template that your are using with your variables and every time you create a new run/debug configuration these values will be set by default. 
Here is an example of setting env. variables for all new local tomcat configs:

1. Go to Run/debug configurations   (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>)
2. Go to defaults - tomcat server - local

Then set the env. variables that you want. now all new local tomcat configs will have this env. variable set.
[image]

Comment: I did that, but the variables are not in scope for any run configuration. I double check again, but that was the issue. I always had to add them to the run config through the environment variables, including the default ones.

Comment: I have added a new solutions. I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned it with the default ones, guess it is either a bug or a not well documented feature. Might be worthwhile to register it as a bug/feature request. A global definition which is automatically inherited would help a lot.

Comment: I've counted yours as the answer to that question, also because it was confirming what I have perceived, therefore filing an issue with IntelliJ, they might be able to give a final answer. Will update on this then.

Comment: Path variables should be automatically inherited from the settings, otherwise it makes no sense. Also because I believe that the defaults are only valid on project scope, when I started a new project the defaults were blank again ... A global definition which is automatically inherited over all scopes and stay persistent like that would help a lot.